# Appending data or inserting to html doesnt show the tags

Tags: php, jquery, html

I just want to paginate the info from my data base sending the data from 3 to 3, but when im making another request for the next data it works and is appended but in the view looks like isnt nothing (as is invisible).

The first append works but the rest doesnt show anything but it can see in the DOM

Php, Jquery, Html

```
function CargarDatos(data){
            let i = false;
            if (i) {
                $('#publicaciones').empty();
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "peticiones.php",
                data: 'id='+data,
                method: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    i = true;

                    $('#publicaciones').append(data);
                }
            });
        }
        CargarDatos();
```

I expect to be shown but it's in the DOM but is invisible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UHvV.png)

Comment: Your first if block will never be true.

Comment: your first if is always false. So, your element is never gonna be empty. And you are not passing any data parameter when calling your function.
`CargarDatos();` but the signature is `function CargarDatos(data){}`

Comment: Ok guys thanks, ill fix that little things. My question is i dont know why the tags are invisible look at the image please.

Comment: If your carosel is styled so that only three will show at any given time, then the 4th and beyond can be invisible due to overflow hidden

Comment: In the DOM only appears the 3 new data when I click on the paginate, but I dont understand why it's invisible